# Is there a tool to assist in producing an XSL, which would translate XMLs described by one XSD to XMLs described by another XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xslt, translation

I am new to XMLs/XSDs/XSLs. I have two XSDs. I wish to generate an XSL that would translate XML files complying with the first XSD to respective XML files complying with the second XSD.

I reckon there are tools that automate this task, given some help from the human, of course.

Do any of you know of such tools?

Thanks a lot in advance.

**P.S.**
I must add that the given XSDs are rather large, I would not like to translate them manually even if I knew XSL, which I don't :-(.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using Altova's XmlSpy and MapForce for that. Here is the link http://www.altova.com/mapforce/xml-mapping.html. The tool is not free, but it's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to answer with [MapForce](http://www.altova.com/mapforce/xml-mapping.html) but Superfilin was first. But the [MissionKit](http://www.altova.com/missionkit/xml-developers.html) might be a more practical product since it includes MapForce but also adds XmlSpy and StyleVision. XmlSpy is useful for designing XSD schema's while StyleVision is practical to translate XML to RTF documents or HTML pages. (And even to PDF, although I never used that feature.) The [Architect](http://www.altova.com/missionkit/software-architects.html) version also offers UML modelling, which can be practical and DatabaseSpy, which is something I really like when designing databases for SQL Server.

There is an alternative from [Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/) but it's quality is not as good as MapForce.